# C# NUnit reports weird error: "No suitable constructor was found"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, constructor

I'm using VS2019 and created a NUnit test project with a .NET Core template, then I added this code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace xxx
{
    class Immutable
    {
        public Immutable(string _cur, string _addr)
        {
            Currency = _cur;
            Address = _addr;
        }

        public string Currency { get; }
        public string Address { get; }

        [Test]
        public static void Test() // reports this line has problem?
        {
            var m = new Immutable("usd", "us");
            string s = m.Currency;
            Assert.AreEqual("usd", s);
        }
    }
}
```

Build ok, but when I run it, test explorer reports this:

```
Test
Source: xxx.cs line 17
Duration: < 1 ms

Message: 
    OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found
```

I don't quite get what the problem is, how to fix it?

Comment: NUnit test methods are (typically) instance methods. .NET tests are normally structured so that you have your code in one project (commonly a class library, but it can be an application), and then a separate test project which contains your test fixtures, and references your project containing your code. You don't normally embed test methods *inside* your code to be tested. In theory, however, NUnit does support static test methods, so I'm not sure why it's trying to instantiate `Immutable`. It should need a `[TestFixture]` attribute on the test fixture though.

Comment: do you test unit test class itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your test class have parameterized constructor, you need TestFixture attribute with parameters to construct it.

Try this:

```
[TestFixuture("usd", "us")]
class Immutable
{
    ...
}
```

See the [document](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute)

And strongly recommend you separate a test class for testing.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ImmutableTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var m = new Immutable("usd", "us");
        string s = m.Currency;
        Assert.AreEqual("usd", s);
    }
}
```